# how to implement parasitic inheritance to avoid nesting

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns, prototype

[image]

I would like to follow the inheritance structure shown above. I would like create an engineer using this syntax:

```
var Mark = new Employee(id).WorkerBee(project).Engineer();
```

To achieve this syntax, I have to create a nested object following a parasitic inheritance pattern like so:

```
    function Employee(id) {
      this.id = id;

      this.WorkerBee = function(project) {
        this.project = project;

        this.Engineer = function() {
          ...
          return this;
        };

        return this;
      };
    }
```

To avoid deep layers of nesting, I am trying to rewrite it using prototypes. How can I rewrite my code to achieve the same goal as above ?

```js
      function Employee(id) {
        //variables
        this.id = id
        this.name = "";
        this.dept = "general";

        //methods
        this.getId = function() {
          return this.id
        }
      }
    Employee.prototype.WorkerBee = WorkerBee;

    function WorkerBee(project) {
      //variables
      this.projectName = project
      this.projects = [];
      //methods
      this.getProjectName = function() {
        return this.projectName
      }
      return this
    }
    WorkerBee.prototype.Engineer = Engineer

    function Engineer() {
      //variables
      this.dept = "engineering";
      this.machine = "";
      //methods
      this.getDept = function() {
        return this.dept
      }
      return this
    }

    var Mark = new Employee("5").WorkerBee("Secret Project").Engineer();
    console.log(Mark.getId()) //should print "5"
    console.log(Mark.getProjectName()) //should print "Secret Project"
    console.log(Mark.getDept()) //should print engineering
```

Comment: *" I have to create a nested object following a parasitic inheritance pattern like so"* Not necessarily, reasonably certain there are simpler ways. Do you necessarily want to use constructor functions to create objects, or are you happy with more direct forms of prototypical inheritance?

Comment: *"I would like create an engineer using this syntax: `var Mark = new Employee(id).WorkerBee(project).Engineer();`"* **Why?** That's extremely convoluted. Why not: `var Mark = new Engineer(id, project);`? That would be *dramatically* more standard, and also very easy to implement.

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
Hey TJ. I know Mark = new Engineer() is the standard way to create it however, I am simply using this example as an analogy. I have some code that do I need to execute in the pattern of Mark = new Employee().WorkerBee().Engineer()

Comment: @ Paolo: Again: **Why**?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My Engineer subclass needs some variables found in the Employee class. There is a quick workaround for this since Engineer is only 2 levels away from Employee but it becomes an issue when I'm in the nth subclass away from Employee. Ideally this nth subclass has access to n-1th's, n-2th... subclass all the way back to Employee

Comment: @ Paolo: Standard inheritance is all that's required for that. You can have as many levels as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I understand partially. What is the reason why you want to do this? Do you just want a shortcut for creating multiple instances using multiple statements?

**Should the instance of `C` returned by `A().B().C()` be any different than the one created with the standard `new C()`?**

If you just want to chain constructors, you can add the context in which they are defined (most likely the global object) to the prototype chain of the created entities. You should be able to do that:

```
var A = function () {};
A.prototype = Object.create(this);
```

What this does not eliminate though is the need for the `new` keyword for instantiation. You would need to do `new (new (new A()).B()).C()`. I can't think of a different approach than having a helper function which would create constructors which do not require the `new` keyword:

```
var define = function (init) {
  var Constructor = function () {
    if (!(this instanceof Constructor)) {
      return new Constructor();
    }
    if (init) {
      init.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
  };
  Constructor.prototype = Object.create(this);
  return Constructor;
};
```

The usage is:

```
var A = define(function (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
});

var a1 = new A(1, 2);
// a1 instanceof A === true
// a1.x === 1
// a1.y === 2

var a2 = A(1, 2);
// a2 instanceof A === true
// a2.x === 1
// a2.y === 2
```

If you have the constructors `A`, `B` and `C`, you can use the following notations interchangeably:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var c = new C();

var a = A();
var b = B();
var c = C();

var b = A().B();
var c = A().C();

var a = B().C().A();
```

In case of `A().B().C()`, you do not have access to the instances of `A` and `B`.

Can you elaborate a bit more on what is your deal?

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

<del>What you have there is madness as you basically merge three constructors and make it seem that `WorkerBee` and `Employee` are actually instantiated while they are not.</del>

<del>I'm not going to question the `new A().B().C()` notation even though I find it quite messed up.</del>

<del>You probably want to make use of the `instanceof` operator the following way.</del>

```
var A = function (x) {
  if (!(this instanceof A)) return new A(x);

  this.x = x;
};

var B = function (y) {
  if (!(this instanceof B)) return new B(y);

  this.y = y;
};

var C = function () {
  if (!(this instanceof C)) return new C();
};

A.prototype.B = B;
B.prototype.C = C;
```

<del>You can now call `new A()` and `A()`, `new B()` and `B()` and `new C()` and `C()` interchangeably while achieving the same result as both of the calls always return an instance of the constructor.</del>

```
new A() instanceof A === true
new A().B() instanceof B === true
new A().B().C() instanceof C === true
```

Comment: Hi Jan, I am simply using the code above as an example. I know the best way to create Engineer would be var Mark = new Engineer(), however I have some code that follows the pattern of Object().Object().Method() and this example is simply a clear way to convey it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you seem to have the belief that you have to use this odd, verbose mechanism in order to have inheritance between Employee <- WorkerBee <- Engineer (and such), but you don't; normal inheritance is all you need for this:

```js
// ==== Employee
function Employee(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
// Add Employee methods to Employee.prototype, e.g.:
Employee.prototype.getId = function() {
    return this.id;
};

// ==== WorkerBee, derived from Employee
function WorkerBee(id, project) {
    // Inheritance, part 1: Chain to the base constructor
    Employee.call(this, id);

    // WorkerBee stuff
    this.project = project;
}

// Inheritance, part 2: Create the object to use for WorkerBee
// instance prototypes, using Employee.prototype as its prototype.
WorkerBee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
WorkerBee.prototype.constructor = WorkerBee;

// Add WorkerBee methods to WorkerBee.prototype, e.g.:
WorkerBee.prototype.getProjectName = function() {
    return this.project;
};

// ==== Engineer, derived from WorkerBee
function Engineer(id, project) {
    // Inheritance, part 1: Chain to the base constructor
    WorkerBee.call(this, id, project);
}

// Inheritance, part 2: Create the object to use for Engineer
// instance prototypes, using WorkerBee.prototype as its prototype.
Engineer.prototype = Object.create(WorkerBee.prototype);
Engineer.prototype.constructor = Engineer;

// Add Engineer methods to Engineer.prototype, e.g.:
Engineer.prototype.getDept = function() {
    return "Engineering";
};

// ==== Usage
var mark = new Engineer("5", "Secret Project");
snippet.log(mark.getId());          // "5"
snippet.log(mark.getProjectName()); // "Secret Project"
snippet.log(mark.getDept());        // "Engineering"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

That's the standard way to do prototypical inheritance using constructor functions in JavaScript (for now; in ES6, you'd use the new `class` feature, which does basically the same thing, with some syntactic sugar). Just add `Manager` (derived from `Employee`) and `SalesPerson` (derived from `WorkerBee`).

On old browsers, you may need a partial polyfill for `Object.create`, which looks like this:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw "The two-argument version of Object.create cannot be polyfilled.";
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;
        return new ctor();
    };
}
```

There are transpilers for taking ES6 source with `class` and turning it into ES5 code. There's also my [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) script, which makes inheritance a lot less verbose.